# Query compare from a table and a sum of multiple row in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, sum

I have a question regarding SQL query and I keep getting an error. So what im trying to do is getting a QTY value from a row in MASTER_DRAWING TABLE and compare it with the same name but with the sum of multiple occurences with the same key HEAD_MARK.

this is my SQL

```
SELECT MASTER_DRAWING.TOTAL_QTY AS TOTALQTY, 
       SUM(MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED.ASSIGNED_QTY) AS SUMASSIGNEDQTY 
FROM MASTER_DRAWING, MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED 
WHERE HEAD_MARK = 'TESTMULTIPLE' AND PROJECT_NAME = 'MILLHOUSE'
```

What I keep getting is 'ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined'

Am I doing something wrong here? in the end, I need to compare TOTALQTY with SUMASSIGNEDQTY for further operation

this is the tabe structure

MASTER_DRAWING,

```
  HEAD_MARK           VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  ENTRY_DATE          DATE,
  COMP_TYPE           VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  WEIGHT              NUMBER(11,2),
  SURFACE             NUMBER(15,3),
  PROFILE             VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  PROJECT_NAME        VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  LENGTH              NUMBER(15,2)              NOT NULL,
  TOTAL_QTY           NUMBER(38),
  SUBCONT_STATUS      VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  DISTRIBUTION_COUNT  NUMBER
```

and MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED,

```
  ASSIGNED_WEIGHT    NUMBER(12,3),
  ASSIGNED_QTY       NUMBER(38),
  SURFACE            NUMBER(15,3),
  SUBCONT_ID         VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  REVISION_NO        NUMBER(2),
  ASSIGNMENT_DATE    DATE,
  PROJECT_NAME       VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  ID                 NUMBER(3),
  HEAD_MARK          VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  ASSIGNED_DUE_DATE  DATE,
  COMP_TYPE          VARCHAR2(25 CHAR),
  SIGNATURE          VARCHAR2(25 CHAR)
```

Comment: How are you joining `MASTER_DRAWING` and `MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED` together? Via which fields are they related?

Comment: @Linger They are two separate table and they must be related via HEAD_MARK and PROJECT_NAME as the key

Comment: That is your WHERE clause but how do you link the tables together.  What field in `MASTER_DRAWING` links to what field in `MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED`?

Comment: Post your table structures to understand the relation between two tables

Comment: @SaharshShah I edited the post with the table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MD.TOTAL_QTY AS TOTALQTY, MDA.SUMASSIGNEDQTY 
FROM MASTER_DRAWING MD 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MDA.HEAD_MARK, MDA.PROJECT_NAME, SUM(MDA.ASSIGNED_QTY) AS SUMASSIGNEDQTY 
            FROM MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED MDA 
            GROUP BY MDA.HEAD_MARK, MDA.PROJECT_NAME
          ) MDA ON MD.HEAD_MARK = MDA.HEAD_MARK AND MD.PROJECT_NAME = MDA.PROJECT_NAME 
WHERE MD.HEAD_MARK = 'TESTMULTIPLE' AND MD.PROJECT_NAME = 'MILLHOUSE';
```

Comment: I don't see any value when I execute that query. it works but I don't see any values. I checked the value on those tables and theyre not null